# How to speed up a function call in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, axios, backend

I'm creating a get request to the backend as soon certain data is posted to the database. So in other to wait for the post request to be completed before a get request is fired, I implemented a waiting logic like so, `postArray.called = true`

```
const postArray = async (arr) => {
    const movie = {
        name: searchTerm,
        result: arr
    }
    try {
        await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: result,
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                "Accept":"application/json"
              }
            })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    postArray.called = true
}
```

To make the get request wait for the post request, I used a if condition like so.

```
app.get("/getNewList", (req, res)=>{
    if(postArray.called){
        process.nextTick(()=>{
            axios.get('http://localhost:3001/List')
                .then(response => res.send(response.data))
                .catch(error => res.send(error))
        })
    }
})
```

The problem is, this get request doesn't get call for another 2 or 3 minutes after the post request has been called. I need a way to speed up this function call so it doesn't slow my app down completely.

Sometimes, the request times out and I get a timeout error.

Is there another way to make this quicker?

////EDIT////

I have been informed that using `if(postArray.called)` is not the same as making the get request wait, so I tried something else.

```
 async function getData(props){
        let Result = []
        let fetchAgain = await axios.get('/getNewList')
        Result = fetchAgain.data.find(x => x.name.toLowerCase() === props.toLowerCase()).result
        showResult(Result)
    }

 async function fetchPost(props){
      axios.post(`/${props}`)
        .then((res) =>{
            if(res.status === 200){
                getData(props)
            }
        }) 
    }
```

This is the new request made from the front end. I declared a function to call the get request, then passed it to the `.then` part of the post request.
this still doesn't work. Keep in mind that `if(postArray.called)` was removed from the get request on the backend

---

The `fetchPost` function was used to send data to my backend which then queries two external APIs:

```
function newFetch(a){
    const promises = [
  Fetch(`https://externalapi1?=${a}.com`,
  Fetch(`https://externalapi2?=${a}.com`,]
    
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(values =>{
            const result = values.filter(o=>Object.values(o).every(v=>v) && Object.entries(o).length);

            postArray(result)}
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

This is where the postArray function is called. Then I intend to fetch this data from the backend to render to my client. Using both failed methods listed above

///End EDIT///

/////This is the place where newFetch was called////

```
app.post("/:endpoint([\\/\\w\\ ]*)", async (req, res) =>{
    newFetchPromise = await newFetch(req.params.endpoint).catch(err => {
        newFetchPromise = null
    })
})
```

Comment: It is unclear what your overall problem is here.  Instead, you're asking about implementation details of some attempted solution (which appears like it may be a flawed direction).  Can you back up and describe the overall problem you're trying to solve here, describe the incoming requests and what those are supposed to do.

Comment: FYI, `if (postArray.called)` doesn't make anything wait for completion.  That just checks a flag and executes another branch of code if that flag isn't true.  There's no waiting in your code.

Comment: The  ```if (postArray,called)``` does check if the post request has been called and prevents the get function from running before that. This truly is an implementation problem, I just don't know how to get it done differently. It works, but takes too long to make the get requests, I need ideas to speed this procedure up

Comment: Well, if this is your entire `app.get("/getNewList", ...)` handler, then if `postArray.called` is not true, then that GET request never returns anything.  I just leaves the client hanging forever waiting for a response until it eventually times out.  This doesn't wait for anything.

Comment: The post request gets called each time, but then can you suggest any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Plus using `postArray.called` looks like a concurrency problem waiting to happen if you have multiple clients accessing your server.

Comment: Accomplish what?  I don't understand what you're really trying to do here.  I asked you to back up a few steps and describe the problem from the beginning because this still looks like a flawed approach to some problem, but I don't understand what exactly the problem is.  If you want to wait for a post request to finish, you would typically use a promise that it returns and use `.then()` or `await` on that promise.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I'm calling an api, which fetches some data and then sends to my database using that post request, I then want to fetch the said data to be rendered on my client. I tried but the structure of my program does not permit me to send it straight to client and I also want in my in db. However I want to ensure the data is in my db before sending a get request.    I would use a ```.then()``` , but without gettting any response from post, can I still use the ```.then()``` function?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not following.  Where is `postArray()` called?  Also, please put any clarifications to your question in the question itself.  Others shouldn't have to read and follow all the comments to understand your question.

Comment: ```postArray``` is called at the backend. I'm trying to get this across as smooth as possible. ```postArray``` carries out the post request

Comment: Please be more specific and show the actual code that calls `postArray()`.  "In the back-end" doesn't tell me anything useful.  I want to see the EXACT sequence of events and code from start to finish here. Something happens that triggers `postArray()` to get called.  Show that code, please.  Then explain what that code has to do with the `.get()` route you show here.  Your are seriously resisting showing the WHOLE problem here and that keeps us from offering you a good way to solve the problem.  I've now asked three times.  Nothing else I can do here.

Comment: I'm going to further edit the question so as to include as the info you've asked

Comment: Who calls `newFetch()`?   Is that called from a route handler?  Is this whole operation something that happens globally on the server or happens on behalf of a single user?  I ask because this will require keeping track of some state in the server so some future request can know when some prior operation is finished and I'm trying to see if this is global state per server or per-user state.

Comment: Its a global function on the sever side. newFetch is triggered on the backend when ```fetchPost``` is called on the front end. The frontend sends an argument/string to the backend thru ```fetchPost``` using the post request. ```newFetch``` then gets it, using promise.all. and send the returned data to my db. After which a get request is made from the client to the backend to the db.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to make the get request wait for this process to be completed. That is, for ```fetchPost``` to trigger ```newFetch``` which then calls ```postArray```.  After all this, then the get request ```getData``` should be called. My previous method works, but it takes nearly 3mins after the ```postArray``` has already ran

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a per-server operation, not a per-user operation...

First, fix `newFetch()` so that it returns a promise that is tied to when `postArray()` is done:

```
function newFetch(a) {
    const promises = [
        Fetch(`https://externalapi1?=${a}.com`),
        Fetch(`https://externalapi2?=${a}.com`),
    ];
    return Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
        const result = values.filter(o => Object.values(o).every(v => v) && Object.entries(o).length);
        return postArray(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        // log and rethrow so caller sees the error
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    });
}
```

Then, wherever you call `newFetch()`, you need to save the returned promise into a module-level variable:

```
 // module level variable
 let newFetchPromise;


 // wherever you call newFetch()
 newFetchPromise = newFetch(...).catch(err => {
     newFetchPromise = null;
 });
```

Then, in your route handler, you can wait for that module-level promise:

```
app.get("/getNewList", (req, res)=>{
    if (newFetchPromise) {
        // wait for newFetchPromise
        // this will work whether newFetchPromise has already finished or is still
        // processing
        newFetchPromise.then(() => {
            return axios.get('http://localhost:3001/List');
        }).then(response => {
            res.send(response.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            // maybe want to set an error status here?
            res.send(err);
        });
    } else {
        // have to send some sort of response here if there was no newFetchPromise
        console.log("no newFetchPromise to wait for");
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

As `newFetch()` is called again, it will just update the module-level newFetchPromise to the latest one so any new `/getNewList` requests will always wait for the latest promise while any prior ones will wait for the same one they originally waited for.

Comment: @Imhotep - I'm not sure I fully understood who calls who, but hopefully you can use this example to see how you can create a module-level promise and then how a request handler can wait for that promise to finish before proceeding with the rest of its job.  And, that will work whether the promise has already resolved or has not yet resolved.

Comment: Firstly I want to thank you for taking the pain to do this, I implemented your solution but there's this error, I've been trying to fix it myself, but I couldn't || Error: ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON ``` it originated where ```newFetch``` was called. ```app.post("/:endpoint([\\/\\w\\ ]*)", async (req, res) =>{
    newFetchPromise = await newFetch(req.params.endpoint).catch(err => {
        newFetchPromise = null;
    })
})``` I declared as a module variable just like u said

Comment: Posting this now I realise it was not properly formatted and might be confusing. I am going to paste at the bottom of the original question. Its the function where ```newFetch``` was called from the frontend ```post``` request.

Comment: That error comes from trying to convert something to JSON that has circular references in it.  Perhaps from `res.send(response.data);`.  Also, `newFetchPromise = await newFetch(...)` is wrong.  Remove the `await`.  You want `newFetchPromise` to immediately be the promise, not wait until the promise has resolved.

Comment: I removed the ```await```, but its the same. Here is the full error statement, originated at that very same spot I pointed earlier ```at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:1404) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)```

Comment: This time I removed ```data``` from ```response.data``` like you pointed out. The error stopped but the code seems to be stuck. the  looks like ```postArray``` is not getting called this time

Comment: @Imhotep - I can't do this any more.  I don't know what code you're running now and I can't answer micro questions about code I can't see and structure I don't understand.  I tried to help, but for whatever reason your explanation and my way of understanding are just not on the same plane today.  I have to see the code for the entire process from start to finish so I can see exactly what the sequence of events is.  And, for the error you were getting about a circular structure, I'd have to see the actual data and know exactly what you want to send back.